# align multiple equations without amsmath package

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, subequations

I have to use iopart document class. One of major problems which I came across is aligning multiple equations. For example, for reach

```
\begin{align}
  a & = b \label{eq1} \\
    c & = d \label{eq2}
\end{align}
```

we must use either `amsmath` package or other ones. Unfortunately, iopart does not coincide with it. In this situation how can I align my equations that have gotten me to stack?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete (compilable) minimal example?

Comment: Then try with older format, `\begin{eqnarray}...\end{eqnarray}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}` to align multiple equations without to use `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{lCr}
 a & = b \label{eq1} \\
c & = d \label{eq2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you help me to understand that the difference between general `eqnarray` and `IEEEeqnarray`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Hi. Your question is correct and I'll give you the correct explanations. If you go to pag. 8, you can read that *The eqnarray-environment, however, has a few very severe disadvantages:*; *The spaces around the equality signs are too big. Particularly, they are not the
same as in the multline-and equation-environments*; The expression sometimes overlaps with the equation number even though there
would be enough room on the left, etc.I suggest the tutorial [guide](http://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the package `witharrows` which provides an environment `DispWithArrows` which has by default exactly the same behaviour as the environment `align` of `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{iopart}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows}
  a & = b \label{eq1} \\
    c & = d \label{eq2}
\end{DispWithArrows}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation of the code above]

With `DispWithArrows`, you have the ability to add arrows on the right for explanations (hence the name):

```
\documentclass{iopart}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows}
  a & = b \Arrow{explanation} \label{eq1} \\
    c & = d \label{eq2}
\end{DispWithArrows}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation of the code above]

Answer (score 2):

With `mathenv` (good old) package which significantly improve `eqnarray` environment (package is based on `mdwtab`'s table handling macros).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathenv}

\begin{document}
    \begin{eqnarray}[rl]
a   & = b \label{eq1} \\
c   & = d \label{eq2}
    \end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compliments for using an old but efficient package :-)